# Kinetic JS – Draw two connected lines and measure the angle

Tags: kineticjs, angle

I have developed this canvas http://jsfiddle.net/user373721/dT8qM/

It works great except, I am getting the wrong angle value.  To try the example, please press down the left mouse button on the canvas, drag it to draw the first line, then release the left button, move the cursor where the second line ends (it will be great if the user can see the line being drawn) then press the mouse button again.  The angle value will show; I am using the following to calculate the angle:

```
 angle = (Math.atan2(ay2 - ay1, ax2 - ax1)).toFixed(2);
```

Would appreciate your suggestions, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a function to give you the degree-angle of lines [x1,y1,x2,y2] and [x2,y2,x3,y3] assuming a clockwise sweep.

```
    function degreeAngle(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3){
        var theta1=Math.atan2( (y1-y2),(x1-x2) );
        var theta2=Math.atan2( (y3-y2),(x3-x2) );
        var theta=(theta2-theta1)*180/Math.PI;
        theta=(theta+360)%360;
        return(theta.toFixed(2));
    }
```

[image]

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/99BBm/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var x1=50;
    var y1=50;
    var x2=100;
    var y2=125;
    var x3=250;
    var y3=75;
    var angle=degreeAngle(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3);

    ctx.moveTo(x1,y1);
    ctx.lineTo(x2,y2);
    ctx.lineTo(x3,y3);
    ctx.stroke();
    endingArrow(x2,y2,x3,y3);
    ctx.font="18px Verdana";
    ctx.fillText(angle+" degrees",40,200);

    function degreeAngle(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3){
        var theta1=Math.atan2( (y1-y2),(x1-x2) );
        var theta2=Math.atan2( (y3-y2),(x3-x2) );
        var theta=(theta2-theta1)*180/Math.PI;
        theta=(theta+360)%360;
        return(theta.toFixed(2));
    }

    function endingArrow(x,y,xx,yy){
        var endRadians=Math.atan((yy-y)/(xx-x));
        endRadians+=((xx>x)?90:-90)*Math.PI/180;
        ctx.save();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.translate(xx,yy);
        ctx.rotate(endRadians);
        ctx.moveTo(0,0);
        ctx.lineTo(8,20);
        ctx.lineTo(-8,20);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.restore();
    }

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you Mark, your solution gives me a very good idea on to how to fix my project, becasuse I am drawing the line dynamicaly on the canvas using the mouse, and thanks for adding the arrow head it helps.

Comment: Mark, worked great, except I am not using clockwise sweep, the user can draw lines in different positions.  For example if I try to draw a 270 degree I get -90!  Any suggestions.

Comment: No problem...If you don't want to report negative degrees, just normalize the angle like this: angle = (angle+360)%360   ;)

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, unfortunately it did not work, I have updated the example http://jsfiddle.net/user373721/dT8qM/3/

Comment: You have to **do the normalizing before toFixed(2)** because toFixed turns the number into a string--causing your math to fail.  I've updated the degreeAngle in my answer to reflect this.